# Unable to align div and span

Tags: html, css

I am unable to align the div and a span next to each other the code I am using is

```html
    <div style="float:left;width:35%;max-width:150px;height:30vh;max-height:200px;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url('http://placehold.it/150x200')"></div> 
      
    <span style="margin-left:10px;float:left;font-weight:bold;font-size:22px; display:inline-block;white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden !important;text-overflow: ellipsis;float:right">ssddsa.hksbkjasdouahdohjaqios'djqw'eodhj;oewdh;oeuwdh;eouwhd;uehwd;iuewghd;iuewhgd;ehwdp;i7euwhgd;pi7hywe;idhg;iwedhouw9ehdiouwehdi;uhwe;iduheiuwdh;eiuwhd;iuwehdiuwehdiuhwediuwhdiuhweiudiuewhdiusdds</span>
```

Comment: Ugh. Please avoid inline CSS where possible.  Could you maybe separate that out for us into some readable CSS rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the width of `span` is too wide to fit next to your `div`.

You must specify a width on `span`

```
<span style="width:35%; margin-left:10px;float:left;font-weight:bold;font-size:22px; display:inline-block;white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden !important;text-overflow: ellipsis;float:right">ssddsa.hksbkjasdouahdohjaqios'djqw'eodhj;oewdh;oeuwdh;eouwhd;uehwd;iuewghd;iuewhgd;ehwdp;i7euwhgd;pi7hywe;idhg;iwedhouw9ehdiouwehdi;uhwe;iduheiuwdh;eiuwhd;iuwehdiuwehdiuhwediuwhdiuhweiudiuewhdiusdds</span>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ff4oduzm/1/

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a `float:right;` and `float: left;` on your `span` element, second, your `span` element needs a width. Try `width: 65%;`

Answer (score 0):

test this

http://jsfiddle.net/n8n7pyxk/

```
<div style="float:left;width:35%;max-width:150px;height:30vh;max-height:200px;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url('http://placehold.it/150x200')"></div> 

<span style="margin-left:10px;float:left;font-weight:bold;font-size:22px; display:inline-block;white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden !important;text-overflow: ellipsis;float:right">ssddsa.hksbkjasdouahdohjaqios'djqw'eodhj;oewdh;oeuwdh;eouwhd;uehwd;iuewghd;iuewhgd;ehwdp;i7euwhgd;pi7hywe;idhg;iwedhouw9ehdiouwehdi;uhwe;iduheiuwdh;eiuwhd;iuwehdiuwehdiuhwediuwhdiuhweiudiuewhdiusdds</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
float:left;
width:35%;
max-width:150px;
height:30vh;
max-height:200px;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-image:url('http://placehold.it/150x200');
}
span {
margin-left:10px;
float:left;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:22px;
display:inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden !important;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div> 
<span>This is span</span> 
</body>
</html>
```

Worked Fine ! [image]

Reason : by putting so much words without space in span , the width became so long .
You also used float:right in the end of span style which does not help this out !